# printf() in my CUDA kernel doesn't result produce any output

Tags: cuda, printf

I have added some `printf()` statements in my CUDA program

```
__device__ __global__ void Kernel(float *, float * ,int );
void DeviceFunc(float *temp_h , int numvar , float *temp1_h)
{ .....
    //Kernel call
    printf("calling kernel\n");
    Kernel<<<dimGrid , dimBlock>>>(a_d , b_d , numvar);
    printf("kernel called\n");
  ....
}

int main(int argc , char **argv)
{   ....
    printf("beforeDeviceFunc\n\n");
    DeviceFunc(a_h , numvar , b_h); //Showing the data
    printf("after DeviceFunc\n\n");
    ....
}
```

Also in the Kernel.cu, I wrote:

```
#include<cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>
__device__ __global__ void Kernel(float *a_d , float *b_d ,int size)
{
    int idx = threadIdx.x ;
    int idy = threadIdx.y ;
    //Allocating memory in the share memory of the device
    __shared__ float temp[16][16];

    //Copying the data to the shared memory
    temp[idy][idx] = a_d[(idy * (size+1)) + idx] ;
    printf("idx=%d, idy=%d, size=%d", idx, idy, size);
    ....
}
```

Then I compile using `-arch=sm_20` like this:

```
nvcc -c -arch sm_20 main.cu
nvcc -c -arch sm_20 Kernel.cu
nvcc -arch sm_20 main.o Kernel.o -o main
```

Now when I run the program, I see:

```
beforeDeviceFunc

calling kernel
kernel called
after DeviceFunc
```

So the `printf()` inside the kernel is not printed. How can I fix that?

Comment: In my case `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` returned no errors. However I noticed block dimensions were too big (32 x 32) and creating smaller thread blocks solved the problem.

Answer (score 16):

`printf()` output is only displayed if the kernel finishes successfully, so check the return codes of all CUDA function calls and make sure no errors are reported.

Furthermore `printf()` output is only displayed at certain points in the program. [Appendix B.32.2 of the Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#limitations) lists these as

- Kernel launch via `<<<>>>` or `cuLaunchKernel()` (at the start of the launch, and if the CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING environment variable is set to 1, at the end of the launch as well),
- Synchronization via `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`, `cuCtxSynchronize()`, `cudaStreamSynchronize()`, `cuStreamSynchronize()`, `cudaEventSynchronize()`, or `cuEventSynchronize()`,
- Memory copies via any blocking version of `cudaMemcpy*()` or `cuMemcpy*()`,
- Module loading/unloading via `cuModuleLoad()` or `cuModuleUnload()`,
- Context destruction via `cudaDeviceReset()` or `cuCtxDestroy()`.
- Prior to executing a stream callback added by `cudaStreamAddCallback()` or `cuStreamAddCallback()`.

To check this is your problem, put the following code after your kernel invocation:

```
{
    cudaError_t cudaerr = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaerr != cudaSuccess)
        printf("kernel launch failed with error \"%s\".\n",
               cudaGetErrorString(cudaerr));
}
```

You should then see either the output of your kernel or an error message.

More conveniently, [`cuda-memcheck`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#limitations) will automatically check all return codes for you if you run your executable under it. While you should always check for errors anyway, this comes handy when resolving concrete issues.

Comment: I get `kernel launch failed with error "CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version".`

Comment: Then check your installation and make sure the newest (or a sufficiently recent) driver is installed.

Comment: I don't have root access for updating. Do you know how can I check for errors in cuda 4?

Comment: I think this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272574/cuda-no-compatible-device-error-on-ubuntu-11-10-12-04) will help you.

Comment: @mahmood what driver version is reported when you run nvidia-smi -a ?

Comment: You will need root access to sort out driver issues, so you'll have to contact the administrator about this. Did you install the CUDA toolkit yourself or was that installed by the administrator as well? It's surprising they do not match. If you can't get him to upgrade to a recent driver version then your only chance is to use an older CUDA version that works with the driver you have.

Comment: Before you contact your administrator however, answer Robert's question first.

Comment: Hi, I also have the same issue and tried your answer. I didn't get any error, but no printf lines inside kernels are printed.

Comment: I am just printing threadIdx.x, but not working. What might be the problem? (@RobertCrovella)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error just now and decreasing the block size to 512 helped. According to documentation maximum block size can be either 512 or 1024.

I have written a simple test that showed that my GTX 1070 has a maximum block size of 1024. UPD: you can check if your kernel has ever executed by using cudaError_t cudaPeekAtLastError() that returns cudaSuccess if the kernel has started successfully, and only after it is worse calling cudaError_t cudaDeviceSynchronize().

Testing block size of 1023

Testing block size of 1024

Testing block size of 1025

CUDA error: invalid configuration argument

Block maximum size is 1024

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <iostream>

__global__
void set1(int* t)
{
    t[threadIdx.x] = 1;
}

inline bool failed(cudaError_t error)
{
    if (cudaSuccess == error)
        return false;

    fprintf(stderr, "CUDA error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int blockSize;
    for (blockSize = 1; blockSize < 1 << 12; blockSize++)
    {
        printf("Testing block size of %d\n", blockSize);
        int* t;
        if(failed(cudaMallocManaged(&t, blockSize * sizeof(int))))
        {
            failed(cudaFree(t));
            break;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < blockSize; i++)
            t[0] = 0;
        set1 <<<1, blockSize>>> (t);
        if (failed(cudaPeekAtLastError()))
        {
            failed(cudaFree(t));
            break;
        }
        if (failed(cudaDeviceSynchronize()))
        {
            failed(cudaFree(t));
            break;
        }

        bool hasError = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < blockSize; i++)
            if (1 != t[i])
            {
                printf("CUDA error: t[%d] = %d but not 1\n", i, t[i]);
                hasError = true;
                break;
            }
        if (hasError)
        {
            failed(cudaFree(t));
            break;
        }

        failed(cudaFree(t));
    }
    blockSize--;
    if(blockSize <= 0)
    {
        printf("CUDA error: block size cannot be 0\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Block maximum size is %d", blockSize);
    return  0;
}
```

P.S. Please note, that the only thing in block sizing is warp granularity which is 32 nowadays, so if 0 == yourBlockSize % 32 the warps are used pretty efficiently. The only reason to make blocks bigger then 32 is when the code needs synchronization as synchronization is available only among threads in a single block which makes a developer to use a single large block instead of many small ones. So running with higher number of smaller blocks can be even more efficient than running with lower number of larger blocks.

Comment: Your error checking is incorrect, as is your statement "Note that if block size provided exceeds the maximum block size, the kernel just doesn't run without any exceptions, errors etc". And the block size limits, etc are fully described in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Is I mentiond "at least I don't know where to get [the error]", I have found out that calling cudaPeekAtLastError helps and updated the answer

Comment: Depending on the Cuda compute capability of the GPU, the number of blocks per multiprocessor is more or less limited. E.g. 2.x supports 1536 threads per SM, but only 8 blocks. If you just use one full warp per block, the maximum number of threads is 256, which makes it more difficult to hide latencies. Beside synchronization and latencies, cache utilization is a further reason to let threads run on the same SM. A for loop is an alternative with a high enough number of threads (to hide latencies) and blocks (to utilize all SM) for cache utilization.