# see the content of variables inside the kernel with cuda

Tags: cuda, printf

I need to see the content of a variable which is on the device? 
it is possible inside the kernel?
I tried to use printf as usualy but it doesn't work.
Thank you in advance

Comment: printf should work, but the internal buffer to flush the printed strings is limited. If your block/thread counts are large, this might not print anything (overflow). 
Try to shrink the grid configuration, or to use an actual debugger, such nsight or cuda-gdb.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320321/printf-with-arch-sm-20-doesnt-show-anaything-in-the-kernel-file/13321253#13321253) may help.